# What's The Best Way To Include Option Outside Of Mat-Group?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently have a group where we'd like most of them to be separated, but there are a few which should not be grouped, is there a way to handle these without creating options manually or a second array ?

current result:

[image: current result]

expected result:

[image: expected result]

code:

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
          <mat-select matNativeControl disableOptionCentering [(ngModel)]="selectedTemplate" (selectionChange)="validateTemplateFields(newImpressionDateRef.invalid)" placeholder="Select One">
            <mat-option hidden [value] = "" selected>Select One</mat-option>
            <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of templateGroups" [label]="group.name">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let template of group.templates" matTooltip="template.title" [value]="template.id">
              {{template.title}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-optgroup>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

```
  templateGroups = [
    {
      name: "",
      templates: [
        {
          "id": this.clinicalImpressionPlanType,
          "title": 'Free Text Narrative',
          "disabled": false,
          "visible": true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "SNF/RNF",
      templates: [
        {"id": this.nomncType, "title": 'NOMNC (SNF/RNF)', "disabled": false, "visible": true, "TeamQueue": "SNF/RNF" },
        {"id": this.icsType, "title": 'Initial Continued Stay', "disabled": false, "visible": true, "TeamQueue": "SNF/RNF" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Home Health",
      templates: [],
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

can hide the label using a class based on when the name is empty

```
<mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of templateGroups" [class.hideLabel]="group.name == ''" [label]="group.name">
```

---

```
::ng-deep .mat-optgroup.hideLabel .mat-optgroup-label {
  display: none;
}
```